# How to build a RPM package using Maven on Travis?

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I am trying to build my Maven project on Travis. The build process seems to work excepting the built of the RPM package.

I am using the plugin [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/). The reason seems to be that the RPM binary is not available.

Is there a way to build my RPM package with Travis ?

Here is the location of my project:
https://travis-ci.org/qwazr/QWAZR

Thanks for help.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:rpm (generate-rpm) on project
>   qwazr: Unable to query for default vendor from RPM: Error while
>   executing process. Cannot run program "rpm": error=2, No such file or
>   directory -> [Help 1]

Comment: You will not be able to build an RPM on travis cause oyu need to have installed the rpm command which the above error messages expresses.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understood the reason, the error message was pretty clear.  In comparison, JDEB was able to generate the Debian package (probably because there is no external binary dependency), my main question remains, and I can rewrite it so: Is there an alternative (and recommended) way to build a RPM package on Travis ?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know of a Maven Plugin which can create RPM's with pure java...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a full java implementation.

https://github.com/craigwblake/redline

I will test it and edit this response to confirm it works.